# java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'user_details' for update in FROM clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on hibernate with MySql and try to update record it give me error.

**Code**

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("update UserDetails set userStatus=:userStatus where id =(select max(id) from UserDetails where  department=:department)");
    query.setParameter("userStatus", "ACTIVE");
    query.setParameter("department",55);
    int result=query.executeUpdate();
```

**StakeTrace:**

```
  org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
  at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:110)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:421)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:283)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1278)
  at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117)
  at com.nextenders.dao.TestDao.checkmysql(TestDao.java:58)
  at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.facade.JUnitFacade.main(JUnitFacade.java:17)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'user_details' for update in FROM clause
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
  at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:175)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:101)
... 6 more
```

Can any body help me to correct this?

Comment: First, turn on SQL command logging and print the actual SQL that Hibernate is executing.

Comment: update user_details set user_status='ACTIVE' where id =(select max(id) from user_details where  department_id=55);

Answer (score 1):

update UserDetails set userStatus=:userStatus where department=:department

Answer (score 1):

As i am right your sql is to complex try:

```
update UserDetails set a.userStatus=:userStatus where department=:department
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think HQL supports update statements like this. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html for details.

There are "bulk" update statements, but I don't think they support subqueries.

However, since your update statement seems to be pretty plain, you may use a direct SQL statment for the update.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("update UserDetails set userStatus=:userStatus where id in(select id from UserDetails where  department=:department)");
    query.setParameter("userStatus", "ACTIVE");
    query.setParameter("department",55);
    int result=query.executeUpdate();
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the other comments I realize, that your subquery refers to the same table. This is not possible, so you need to simplyfy that as stated in the other answers:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update UserDetails set userStatus=:userStatus where department=:department");
    query.setParameter("userStatus", "ACTIVE");
    query.setParameter("department",55);
    int result=query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought for something to try - no guarantee: name your tables so that the sub query has its own way of addressing the tables. i.e.

"update UserDetails set userStatus=:userStatus where id in(select u2.id from UserDetails as u2 where  u2.department=:department)"

I'm thinking it's getting confused because you're using the same table in the sub query as the one you're updating.

Comment: I'd try Jens' or liuzdcq's answer then.